# gcc -fprofile-arcs: how to output a file on custom RTOS

Tags: c++, gcc, arm, gdb, profiling

`gcc` has a [bunch of options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html#Instrumentation-Options)  you can use for runtime analysis that produce output during the execution of your program.

For example: [gcc -fprofile-arcs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html#Instrumentation-Options)

> Add code so that program flow arcs are instrumented. During execution
>   the program records how many times each branch and call is executed
>   and how many times it is taken or returns. On targets that support
>   constructors with priority support, profiling properly handles
>   constructors, destructors and C++ constructors (and destructors) of
>   classes which are used as a type of a global variable.
>
> When the compiled program exits it **saves this data to a file called
>   auxname.gcda** for each source file. The data may be used for
>   profile-directed optimizations (-fbranch-probabilities), or for test
>   coverage analysis (-ftest-coverage). Each object file’s auxname is
>   generated from the name of the output file, if explicitly specified
>   and it is not the final executable, otherwise it is the basename of
>   the source file. In both cases any suffix is removed (e.g. foo.gcda
>   for input file dir/foo.c, or dir/foo.gcda for output file specified as
>   -o dir/foo.o).

I am running a custom C++ RTOS that does not have a filesystem so the program cannot, as the **bolded** words state, "save" the data using the same mechanism as on Linux/Windows/QNX.

**QUESTION**

How, if possible, could I make use of `-fprofile-arcs` (or any of the other runtime profiling options that produce a file) on my custom RTOS with no filesystem?

Is it possible to redirect the info by providing a "writer" class? If so, I could stream the data to the PC using whatever interface I have available like JTAG.

Speaking of the debugger, is it possible to use `gdb` and the JTAG connection to *somehow* solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something similar once - I was after code coverage. Luckily I was able to get my hands on a VectorCast license, which can instrument the source before compilation and do the bookkeeping in memory. Can't remember how closely I looked at  providing stubs for the instrumented gcc code.

If your focus is profiling in an RTOS embedded environment, you could have a periodic record the program counter and run long enough to collect meaningful data.

Comment: I'd want traces to be triggered on every function entry/exit. Actually, I can already do that using `gcc -finstrument-functions`. I guess I'll just have to come up with my own storage-abstraction in which to store the trace info.